# FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION on Tablet version

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I have an app that is built for both mobile and tablet. Mobile version works fine but tablet gives me an headache.

The app downloads images from an URL and displays them as thumbnails in Gridview.

Android 4.1.2
minSdkVersion ="7"
targetSdkVersion ="17"

It runs fine for the first run but if exit and re-run, it freezes the device(I'm testing on a Google Nexus 7 Tablet) and I will have to restart the device. Again, it only happens on the tablet version.

So, here are the topics I've been researched and analyzed so far but because I'm a newbie, it's little hard to determine what the right solution is. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

- FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION
- android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
- Out Of memory error using Universal Image Loader

Here is the logcat I'm getting on the app crash.

```
05-29 10:29:47.842: W/ActivityManager(485): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.nfc/.handover.HandoverService in 0ms
05-29 10:29:47.852: E/JavaBinder(485): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485): Exception in new application when starting activity com.rssapp.mobile/.MainActivityLarge
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485): android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485):     at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:708)
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:696)
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:4252)
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:4316)
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:386)
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1674)
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485):     at com.android.server.SystemServer.init1(Native Method)
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485):     at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1064)
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-29 10:29:48.012: W/ActivityManager(485):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the Universal Image Loader I'm using.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        applicationController = this;
        File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(getApplicationContext(), "UniversalImageLoader/Cache");

        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .resetViewBeforeLoading()
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .build();

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .threadPoolSize(5)
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()          
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .memoryCache(new LRULimitedMemoryCache(3 * 1024 * 1024)) 
            .discCache(new FileCountLimitedDiscCache(cacheDir, 20)) 
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
            .imageDownloader(new URLConnectionImageDownloader(5 * 1000, 30 * 1000)) 
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
            .enableLogging()
            .build();

        imageLoader.init(config);       
    }
```

This is the MainActivityLarge.java

```
public class MainActivityLarge extends Activity {

    RSSFeed feed;
    GridView gridView;
    CustomListAdapterLarge adapter;
    String feedLink="http://mywebsite.com/feed/";
    ArrayList<RSSItem> rssItems=new ArrayList<RSSItem>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);           

        // set the feed link for refresh
        feedLink = new SplashActivity().RSSFEEDURL;

        // Get feed form the file
        feed = (RSSFeed) getIntent().getExtras().get("feed");

        createFeedGroup();
        // Initialize the variables:
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        // Set an Adapter to the ListView
        adapter = new CustomListAdapterLarge(this,rssItems);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                // actions to be performed when a list item clicked
                int pos = arg2;

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("feed", feed);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityLarge.this, SwipeDetailViewLarge.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                intent.putExtra("type", rssItems.get(pos).getCategory());
                startActivity(intent);

                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left2right,R.anim.right2left);

            }
        });

    }   

    private void createFeedGroup() {
        rssItems=new ArrayList<RSSItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < AppConstants.ARRAY.length; i++) {
            RSSItem rssItem=feed.getMapValues(AppConstants.ARRAY[i]);
            rssItems.add(rssItem);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(adapter!=null){
            adapter.imageLoader.clearMemoryCache();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to stuff an absurd amount of actual data into an Intent itself, vs passing a URL to where the data can be obtained?

Comment: I'm fetching RSS Feed from a URL and display data. Did I answer your question?

Comment: No - the question is, are your putting the data itself into the Intent, or only the URL from which the target of the Intent can fetch the data for itself.

Comment: only the URL. thank you

Comment: Your `onDestroy()` is pretty weird. I think `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` is useless and maybe dangerous.